# Convert defines to BOOST_PP_TUPLE or BOOST_PP_SEQ

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

Is it possible convert `#define Name Alex` to `BOOST_PP_SEQ like (A)(l)(e)(x)` or `BOOST_PP_TUPLE (A,l,e,x)`? And more useful for me (`'A')('l')('e')('x')` or `('A','l','e','x')` respectively?

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible. You can't iterate over or split characters of a token in the preprocessor.